# Is any variant of Sati prescribed for men in scriptures?

Tags: scripture, women, men, sati

It well-known that the [primary purpose of marriage is to begot children](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15174/661).

Since humans begets children through sexual reproduction. **The role of men is very limited.** He needs to contribute his tejas, which may take few minutes. But, the role of women is important and it takes atleast nine months. Mother's disposition [can effect the child](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19523/661). So, it may be illogical to argue that both men and women are equal in all the aspects whenever married life is concerned. A men can give birth to large number of off-springs. But , comparatively a women can give birth to very less number of off-springs in her life time by means of natural reproduction. Similarly, there are several inherent differences in dharmas, genes, physical restrictions, capabilities etc.,

But, this question is only regarding the practice of Sati in scriptures.

If husband of a women dies, then she has multiple options: Sati, [begetting children through niyoga](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7625/which-hindu-text-generally-describes-the-rules-of-niyoga), [marrying husband's brother](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15560/661) dharma are three among them. Along with the three mentioned, she can also spend the time at her own will like Satyavati, Satyabhama (as vanaprastha) etc., Niyoga and remarriage are [banned in Kaliyuga](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16947/661).

Does any scripture prescribed any variant of Sati for men? If yes, what are those methods of leaving body after the departure of his wife? If no, is there any reason for not prescribing such an act for men?

This question has no yuga restrictions, if any variant of Sati is mentioned for men in any yuga, it is allowed to mention it.

---

Possible reasons I am thinking:

There is a [restriction for grihastra man to beget children](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/4103/661) for clearing pitru-runa, which may not be mandatory for women. If it is a valid reason, then can he leave after begetting children if his wife departures?

Comment: I remember reading that a person can do prayopavesa if his wife departures and there are no other purposes left...

Comment: No. The husband is a God/Devta for the wife and only service to him will land her a place in heaven. After she jumps into his funeral pyre, she will serve him in the next life too.

Comment: @R.Kaushik Please read the question in detail...

Comment: You are saying father is not equal to mother. Again, please stop feminist extremism.

Comment: @R.Kaushik not equal in which aspect?

Comment: I do not think Sati is "prescribed" for women. Do you have any references to back this assertion?

Comment: @sbharti Okay. I mean 'as an option'.

Comment: I have read whole Mahabharat and Ramayan but did not encounter much of Sati (pandav one is only prominent one). In Ramayan no lady died for her husband on pyre. Some puranas I have read but Sati does not feature much. Sati is rarest of rarest form of devotion. It was never popular but possibly some bhatke hue communities may have forced it. British of course highlighted is as ghar ghar ki kahani.

Comment: There is sannyasa ashrama for men, the rules of which are tougher than death. Kshatriya man has to stake life in battle field. Every man is accountable for wellbeing of his mother/wife/daughter/sister. Rules for men are far tougher than sati.

Comment: The role of men is essential. They were the providers, protectors, and sustainers of the family. Also, Sati was a choice if a wife felt she couldn't live any longer without her husband other options of remarriage and the most prescribed approach which is sanyasi were acceptable. Niyogi was only prescribed for royals because purity was a big factor in the public image of the hier. If nyogi hadn't taken place there would be effectively no hier for the kingdom. If they chose some random person even a young child his image may not fair well in society as king due to his birth.

Comment: That's why Ved Vysa was appointed for Niyogi as he was respectful and his conceiving a child with the aforementioned queens since their husband died early would not be seen as bad since he had a religious role.

Comment: To your question is there something like Sati for men in case their queen dies is possibly their immersion into the Ganges?